# VBA Excel: deleting rows based on value in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, vba7

I am currently trying to clean up my dataset. I currently have two sheets: "sheet1" & "sheet2".
The first 11 columns from sheet2 are linked to sheet1, and are therefore identical. However, a 13th column is included in sheet2 which is either "Yes" or "No".

My goal is to make a VBA macro which deletes a specific row in sheet1 when that exact row in sheet2 (column 13), presents "Yes". However, with my current code, only the top (i = 2) rows from sheet2 get deleted.

The thought behind it is that when a row is deleted in sheet1, and sheet2 is linked to sheet1, sheet2 will automatically be deleted.

My current code:

```
Sub Coentunnel_Delete_rows()
    Dim Acc As Worksheet
    Dim Rev As Worksheet
    Set Acc= Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rev= Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For i = 2 To Acc.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Rev.Cells(i, 13).Value = "Yes " Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        If Rev.Cells(i, 13).Value = "Yes " Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Two things:  first, be sure to [qualify your references](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references) because `Rows(i)` refers to the currently active worksheet only. Second, when you're deleting rows, it's usually best to delete from the [bottom up](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-delete-row/#h-example-5)

Comment: Even better, use `Union` to create a range to delete, and only delete *after* looping.

Comment: @PeterT, thank you for your reply. However, if I do not use Rows(i) as this only directs to the current sheet, how can I select specific rows in sheet1 that correspond to sheet2 (when rev.cells(i,13).value = "Yes "?

Comment: @bigben, thank you for your reply. If I were to use the Union function, how do I reference the correct rows in sheet1 that correspond to sheet2 when the condition is met?

Comment: Using `i`, as you are doing now.

Comment: @Hajoroeters... the statement should specify which sheet has the row to delete, e.g. `Rev.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` or `Acc.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete`